# insertxmlchild() doesn't insert nodes because of invalid URI in xmlns

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, xmltype

I'm trying to insert nodes into an *XMLTYPE* in oracle using *INSERTXMLCHILD*, but nodes are not inserted into the *XML* and when i deleted *the* URI pointed by the default namespace *xmlns* it worked so the *URI* must be invalid.
Is there any chance of this procedure working without deleting the *URI* ?

Thanks;

Comment: Can you post a code snippet of what you have tried so far?

Comment: I resolved the problem, i used local-name() in the XPath and it worked, thanks.